# How to save POST data of a form after user submission without using Sessions, JSON, Ajax, Hidden input or another file

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

First of all I'll be sincere, I'm a student and I've been asked to do a task that seems impossible to me. I don't like asking questions because generally speaking I've always been able to fix my coding issues just by searching and learning, but this is the first time I've ever been on this possition.

I need to create a php file that contains a form with two inputs that the user fills. Once he clicks submit the website will show on top of it the two values. Till here I haven't had an issue, but here's the problem, the next time the user sends another submission, instead of clearing the last 2 values and showing 2 new ones, now there needs to be 4 values showing.

I know this is possible to do through JSON, the use of sessions, Ajax, hidden inputs or using another file (this last one is what I would decide to use if I could), but the teacher says we gotta do it on the same html file without the use of any of the methods listed earlier. He says it can be done through an Array that stores the data, but as I'll show in my example, when I do that the moment the user clicks submit the array values are erased and created from zero. I know the most logical thing to do is asking him, but I've already done that 4 times and he literally refuses to help me, so I really don't know what to do, other than asking here. I should point out that the answer has to be server side, because the subject is "Server-Side Programming".

Thank you for your help and sorry beforehand because I'm sure this will end up being a stupid question that can be easily answered.

For the sake of simplicity I erased everything that has to do with formatting. This is the code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['activity']) && isset($_POST['time'])){
        $agenda = array();
        $activity = $_POST['activity'];
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $text = $activity." ".$time;
        array_push($agenda, $text);
        foreach ($agenda as $arrayData){
            print implode('", "', $agenda);
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
            <label for="Activity">Activity</label><br>
            <input name= "activity" type="text"><br><br>
            <label for="Time">Time</label><br>
            <input name= "time" type="time"><br><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would guess maybe the teacher is talking about doing it all client side using localstorage, perhaps

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean ADyson, but I've never seen the word localstorage till now, so that wouldn't make sense, if that's something php related. If you mean local storage as having 2 files locally or something like that, that's exactly what he is asking us not to do... Thanks for the answer, regardless, appreciated.

Comment: It's not PHP related, it's browser related. It means the browser will store the data in its local database instead of your server, thereby removing the need for submitting the data to the server  and maintaining server-side state and sessions - which you say you're banned from doing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: You _could_ use a server-side database to store the data, but if you're not even allowed to have a standard session in use or any hidden fields then I think it would be impossible to retrieve the correct record again from the database on the next request. That's why I suspect an entirely client-side solution might be a valid answer to the problem.

Comment: It has to be server-side, I'm almost sure there's no way of doing it either but he insists there is a way with the use of arrays... I really don't get it.

Comment: Are you sure it has to be server side? You didn't specify that in the question.

Comment: In fact you mentioned "the same HTML file"...which implies it can be plain HTML, not even PHP. Did you get a clear written description of the task from the teacher?

Comment: Are you allowed to save the data back in the dom? from POST using hidden inputs

Comment: @Enoch it's mentioned already that hidden inputs are not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not very clear to be honest but I might have gotten something going for you.

```
<?php

$formaction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    
if (isset($_POST['activity']) && isset($_POST['time'])){
    $agenda = array();

    //if the parameter was passed in the action url
    if(isset($_GET['agenda'])) {
        $agenda = explode(", ", $_GET['agenda']);
    }

    //set activity time
    $text = $_POST['activity']." ".$_POST['time'];

    //push into existing array the new values
    array_push($agenda, $text);

    //print everything
    print implode(", ", $agenda);

    //update the form action variable
    $formaction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?agenda=" . implode(", ", $agenda);
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $formaction; ?>" method="POST">
            <label for="Activity">Activity</label><br>
            <input name= "activity" type="text"><br><br>
            <label for="Time">Time</label><br>
            <input name= "time" type="time"><br><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**SUMMARY**

Since you cant save the posted values into SESSION vars or HIDDEN input, the next best thing would be to append the previous results of the posted form into the form's action url.

When the form is posted, we verify if the query string `agenda` exists, if it does we explode it into an array called `$agenda`. We then concatenate the `$_POST['activity']` and `$_POST['time']` values and push it to the `$agenda array`. We then PRINT the `array $agenda` and update the `$formaction` variable to contain the new values that were added to the array.

In the HTML section we then set the `<form action=""` to be `<form action="<?php echo $formaction; ?>`

Comment: Also a good answer would explain what you've done and why, rather than just leaving people to figure it out

Comment: @ADyson What im doing here is whenever you post the form, the values $_POST['activity'] and $_POST['time'] are concatenated into the variable $text. Then that variable is pushed into the agenda array and the array gets imploded (as a query string)  into the $formaction variable. The $formaction variable is going to be the URL of your form action. The next time you submit the form, it will read the agenda query string and convert it into an array and continue with adding the new values and printing them.

Comment: @ADyson the line **print implode(", ", $agenda);** will display the agenda on the screen. Unless your trying to display that somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not the OP, I'm not trying to do anything, except get you to improve the answer for the benefit of the OP and other readers. I can already see what you've done but that not necessarily the case for someone less experienced. You should edit the answer to add information instead of just commenting. Thanks :-)

Comment: @ADyson Lol while shaking my head atm, I shit the bed on this one. Thanks and will update accordingly.

Comment: You are my saviour slashroot, I could have never thought of a way of doing it like this. It ended up being a bit troublesome because later on I had to use some conditions to add and erase some entries from the array agenda, but it ended up working perfectly with some work. You gave me the push I needed to be able to find the way. Thanks again!

Comment: @Xitomz Glad to hear it all worked out for you!